# C# and ASP.NET MVC : user session mixed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I'm taking over web application from the previous developer.

We are experiencing user session mixed, an user logins but their login email and items in shopping cart are replaced by a different users

I've been reading static property can cause issues like that in .NET web application.

Can this be causing that?

```
public static object GetCurrentObjContext(string contextKey)
{
    object context = null;

    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        context = GetCurrentThreadObjContext(contextKey);
    else
        context = GetCurrentHttpContextObjContext(contextKey);

    return context;
}

/// <summary>
/// sets the current session        
/// </summary>
public static void StoreCurrentObjContext(object context, string contextKey)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        StoreCurrentThreadObjContext(context, contextKey);
    else
        StoreCurrentHttpContextObjContext(context, contextKey);
}
```